# Find hostname of an Windows image

Tags: windows, hostname, forensics

How to find a hostname of a windows image? I've read about looking at the regback files, but also using C:/Windows/Debug/NetSetup.LOG

When navigating to C:/Windows/Debug/NetSetup.LOG it shows several different names, how would I know which one was used as the hostname?

Comment: What format for the Windows image? Where do you find `NetSetup.LOG`?

Comment: E01 file and C:/Windows/Debug/NetSetup.LOG

Comment: So this is an Encase Image File. Could you also post your NetSetup.LOG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computer name is stored here in the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName` `=>` `ComputerName`

The SYSTEM registry hive is stored here, if you need to access the registry without booting Windows : `C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Swisstone said, the current computer name for the Windows image can be found in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName** for Windows 7,8, and 10.  The NetSetup.LOG file can be located specifically at **%windir%\debug** on the Windows image.  If memory serves me correctly, it should of been around since Windows 2000 but I assume you are viewing it from a Win10 box image.  As you probably already know, the log file details the process of joining a domain as well as the details of any problems encountered.  As soon as you join a domain, it should be written to the log file with the  computer name in the log file itself.  Pulling out the log file via EnCase (or whatever tool you use) and viewing it in notepad++ should give you the computer name in the file where joining the domain occurred.  Hope this helps.